# java hashmap cannot convert object

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

> In Hashmap I send a string and a my own class object as parameter i have sent that successfully but when i want that object it cannot be converted
>   it shows the error
>
> > Main.java:37: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Bikede
> >
> > > Bikede obb= e.getValue();

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Bikede
    {
        int bikeno;
        boolean vacancy;
        public Bikede(int a,boolean b)
        {
            bikeno=a;
            vacancy=b;
        }

    }
class Ideone
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=obj.nextInt();

        HashMap<String,Bikede> lh=new HashMap<String,Bikede>();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        int bno;
        boolean parked;
        bno=obj.nextInt();
        parked =true;
        lh.put(""+i,new Bikede(bno,parked));
        }
        for(Map.Entry e:lh.entrySet())
        {

            Bikede obb= e.getValue();
            System.out.println(obb.bikeno);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where can i find the result plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Map.Entry` to this. Use a real IDE like Eclipse, it'll pick up such errors automatically and recommend solutions (which, most of the time, work).

From the perspective of Java Generics, it's a question of parametrising the Entry. The way it is declared there, it isn't parametrised. Either it ought be casted to `Bikede` or parametrised. Since generics are safer and avoid `ClassCastException`, I chose that solution.

```
for (Entry<String, Bikede> e : lh.entrySet()) {
    Bikede obb = e.getValue();
    System.out.println(obb.bikeno);
}
```